# How to pass button's sender.tag to another VC when clicking a button which triggering open another VC

Tags: swift, button, tableview, segue

I'm using a custom tableView Cell, which has a button and some labels in VC1. What I want to do is when I click the button in a row, then open VC2 and send the current label's text(names[i]) to VC2.

But in my case, I stuck at how to pass buttonTag in pressButton func to prepare func `controller.playingSong = names[buttonTag]`. I try to use a global var, then each time prepare() to retrieve that var, but it didn't work property, it seems prepare() will executed before pressButton() method.

Well, I do search a lot but didn't get a solution, could I combine prepare() into my pressButton(), in other word, is the prepare is necessary when using the segue?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    let REUSE_ID = "CustomCell"
    var names = ["first", "second", "third"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonTag = sender.tag
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: REUSE_ID, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.songName.text = names[indexPath.row]
        // cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
            case "playingSongs":
                let controller = segue.destination as! OpenedVC
                controller.playingSong = names[buttonTag]
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are attaching a segue to your button. You can do that, or use a button IBAction. I don't think it works correctly if you do both, which may be the problem you are having.

If you have your button press trigger an IBAction, you can fetch the button tag from the sender parameter to the action, and then have your IBAction code instantiate the view controller and set a property of the view controller to the sender tag before displaying it.

If you want to attach a segue to the button, then the `prepare(for:sender:)` method will get passed the button in the sender parameter. You can then try to cast sender to `UIButton, and if the cast succeeds, fetch the button's tag and pass it along to the destination view controller. Something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
        case "playingSongs":
            if let sendingButton = sender as? UIButton,
               let controller = segue.destination as? OpenedVC { //Don't use a force-cast
                 let buttonTag = sendingButton.tag
                 controller.playingSong = names[buttonTag]
            }
        // The rest of your code to follow
     }
}
```

### EDIT:

I've fixed the code above by changing the two casts in the `if let` optional binding to use `as?`.

Note that you should avoid force-casting (`as!`) since it causes a crash if it fails.

Comment: thanks for your reply, try to use your code, but Xcode prompt me that ```'Any?' is not convertible to 'UIButton'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?``` both for ```sender``` and ```controller```. And if I use ```!``` to force-cast,  then it prompt me that ```Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'OpenedVC'```

Comment: As a beginning Swift developer you should pretend that the `as!` force cast operator doesn't exist (Same goes for the force unwrap `!` operator.) Think of `!` as the "crash if nil" operator. (and `as!` the "crash if the cast fails" operator.) I'll edit my answer to use `as?`, which is what you want. (I forgot that part.)

Comment: First, it is worked now, thank you. And u are 2nd person to ask me not to use ```!```, yes, it is correct, I'm a junior for Swift, sometimes Im just lazy to use Xcode suggestion to correct my code or refuse to use ```?? default``` because it is more typing...

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should accept it. (That is expected behavior on this site. Up-voting good answers is optional, but encoraged. You need to get a little more reputation for that, however.)

Comment: Understand that laziness in programming is a lot like laziness in electrical wiring. It might save you a couple of minutes in the present, and cause your house (app) to burn down at some point in the future.

Comment: I get really busy yesterday. And u guys answers do solve my question, but u are the 1st one to answer, so I will accept your answer. Then I will change my app's cell as custom cell since it is worked in this small test.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't necessarily have to override prepare function.**

**Just write your prepare function's code in pressButton function instead but with a little bit of modification like so:**

```
 @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

                let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourView's StoryBoardID") as! OpenedVC
                controller.playingSong = names[sender.tag]
                present(viewControllerToPresent: controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
```

Hope my answer helps you :)

Comment: Well, your code is working fine when I remove the segue in storyboard as well as prepare() in the VC1. What I'm lacking could be this one ```self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourView's StoryBoardID")```, I simply don't know this method...

Comment: This method is simply creating an instance of a view controller present in current storyboard with given identifier

Answer (score 0):

**You need to change Here if "segue is from Button"**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "playingSongs":
        let controller = segue.destination as! ViewController
        controller.playingSong = names[(sender as! UIButton).tag] //Need Change here
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: great! it works too, I dumb brain didn't figure out to use sender to pass the button.tag:( Actually ur approach & Nouraiz Taimour's could be the 2 ways of mentioned in Duncan C's answer.